# Getting all the time an "infinite Gas Warning" in the Approve&Call function - Why?

Tags: gas, remix, gas-limit, error

I'm new in developing in smartcontracts.

I've got this error:

```
{
    "Creation": {
        "codeDepositCost": "856200",
        "executionCost": "41158",
        "totalCost": "897358"
    },
    "External": {
        "FerrumToken()": "80511",
        "allowance(address,address)": "861",
        "approve(address,uint256)": "20492",
        "approveAndCall(address,uint256,bytes4)": "infinite",
        "balanceOf(address)": "634",
        "burn(uint256)": "42675",
        "burnFrom(address,uint256)": "63577",
        "decimals()": "522",
        "name()": "404",
        "symbol()": "580",
        "totalSupply()": "430",
        "transferFrom(address,address,uint256)": "65901",
        "transferTEST(address,uint256)": "41978",
        "verID()": "672"
    },
    "Internal": {
        "_transfer(address,address,uint256)": "infinite"
    }
}
```

Sourcecode:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) public; }

contract Ferrum {
    // Public variables of the token
    bytes32 public name;
    bytes32 public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals = 5;
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    uint256 public verID = 1.0;

    // This creates an array with all balances
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

    // This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    // This notifies clients about the amount burnt
    event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

    /**
     * Constrctor function
     *
     * Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract
     */

    function TrainingToken(
    ) public {
        totalSupply = 15800000000000;                       // Update total supply with the decimal amount
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = 15800000000000;             // Give the creator all initial tokens
        name = "TrainingToken";                                    // Set the name for display purposes
        symbol = "TT";                                     // Set the symbol for display purposes

    }

    /**
     * Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract
     */
    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        require(_to != 0x0);
        // Check if the sender has enough
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
        // Check for overflows
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]);
        // Save this for an assertion in the future
        uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
        // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        // Add the same to the recipient
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        // Asserts are used to use static analysis to find bugs in your code. They should never fail
        assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
    }

    /**
     * Transfer tokens
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` from your account
     *
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    }

    function transferTEST(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);           // Check if the sender has enough
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]); // Check for overflows
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                    // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                           // Add the same to the recipient
    }


    /**
     * Transfer tokens from other address
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` on behalf of `_from`
     *
     * @param _from The address of the sender
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);     // Check allowance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowance for other address
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens on your behalf
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public
        returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowance for other address and notify
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens on your behalf, and then ping the contract about it
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     * @param _extraData some extra information to send to the approved contract
     */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
        public
        returns (bool success) {
        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
        if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
            spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Destroy tokens
     *
     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly
     *
     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
     */
    function burn(uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);   // Check if the sender has enough
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;            // Subtract from the sender
        totalSupply -= _value;                      // Updates totalSupply
        Burn(msg.sender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Destroy tokens from other account
     *
     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly on behalf of `_from`.
     *
     * @param _from the address of the sender
     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
     */
    function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                // Check if the targeted balance is enough
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);    // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the targeted balance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;             // Subtract from the sender's allowance
        totalSupply -= _value;                              // Update totalSupply
        Burn(_from, _value);
        return true;
    }

}
```

in the section "approveandcall" I've got all the time these warnings, which I can't figure out, why:

[image: Warning Gas]

Can somebody tell me, why this happens with a codesample?

Thanks everybody for help

Answer (score 2):

> I've got this error:

But you don't have any errors. You have two warnings.

One is about the potentially unbounded gas usage of `approveAndCall`. The compiler has no idea how much gas will be consumed because that depends on what contract `tokenRecipient` is going to be called on. There's nothing wrong with getting a gas estimate like this; it just means that the gas usage of the function can't be known at compile time.

The second warning is a message that appears any time you use `require` or `assert`. It tells you when you should use which.

Both warnings make sense given your code. Now that you've read and understood them, you can ignore them.